# SPF Records - How to Name them

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns, spf

I need to create SPF records for my site for emails. I've created the following 4 entries:

I know from reading I should use the following 2 entries for Amazon:

```
"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ?all"
"spf2.0/pra include:amazonses.com ?all"
```

Question:
- should I create 4 entries - 2 TXT and 2 SPF?
- I've named them spf1 and spf2 - is this ok? (I can't use TXT with no name as I'm already using this for another entry.
- Any other advise on how to setup these entries?

Domain: [www.tradies.dating](http://www.tradies.dating)

thanks
Adam

Answer (score 5):

In practice, neither of these records are necessary.  Here's why:

- The two records you've listed are SPF (v=spf1) and Sender-ID (spf2.0/pra).  The latter protocol, Sender-ID, is now obsolete and this record is not required.
- SPF works off the 'mfrom' address - that's the Return Path address.  Amazon SES uses amazonses.com in the Return Path, meaning that receivers won't even check the SPF record you're creating.  So it is not necessary to add it to the SPF record for your domain.

What you need to do is set up DKIM.  Authenticating email from Amazon SES requires the use of Amazon's Easy DKIM system (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim.html) .

Comment: +1 I thought that Amazon doesn't support Sender-ID (anymore?), and that's the first time I see a note about that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than one SPF record, and naming them SPF1 and SPF2 will not work.

You should combine them into one string. https://serverfault.com/questions/586008/multiple-spf-records-for-multiple-domains shows how to do this.